# I can't install theme: theme install failed

Tags: themes, installation, css

The package could not be installed. The style.css stylesheet doesn’t contain a valid theme header.

What do you guys think went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theme’s stylesheet must contain a commented-out header with the theme’s name:

```
/*Theme Name: nameoftheme*/
```

Comment: /*
Theme Name: Star Lyon
Theme URI:
Description: 
Author: 
Version: 1.0
Tags:
*/ Are you saying name of theme shouldn't have whitespace?

Comment: as per above mentioned please dont upload a full zip folder first unzip it and then upload only Star Lyon.zip file(without documents and files).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're trying to upload the entire zip file which also includes documentation and license information. You need to extract the zip to find the theme zip inside. Please check again.

Comment: I'm installing the theme to the wp/theme directory

Answer (score 0):

First, theme support should be via the theme's WP Support page.

But it seems to me that the theme author didn't set up things correctly (hence the 'required license' problem). Which perhaps means that you didn't get the theme via the WP Theme Repository. Which might be not a good thing to do.

Themes require a certain structure and 'header' info. Themes that are submitted to (and approved by) the WP Theme Repository will be checked for required elements.

IMHO, risky to install themes from a non-WP Repository source. But, you should be asking via the theme support page, not here.

Comment: I'm the one who's to build it. #Beginner

Comment: Then that would have been useful information to include in your original question (the fact that you built it). I assume that you are using the theme development guidelines from the WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development , which will have information on the proper syntax of the theme 'header' area, along with the files you should include in a theme. If you follow those guidelines, that will fix your problem.

Comment: Another helpful hint for here: 'answers' are for 'answers', not additional info, which should be added via the 'comment' or 'edit' area of your question. Adding additional info via 'answers' just clutters up things, obscuring the real answer.